# Does anyone knows who is paying for the free (normally paid) Android programs on the Amazon store

Tags: amazon-appstore

I am really curious **who is paying** for the **free applications** you get when installing and using the **Amazon Android market program**?

Is it *Amazon* (to promote their software/online store)?

Is it the *application/game developer*?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No one pays or gets paid.

According to the original version of [Amazon's developer agreement](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/devportal/pdf/Appstore_Distribution_Agreement.pdf) (see section 2(a)) a developer received at least 20% of the price the developer set for the app, regardless of the price Amazon actually sold it for.  But they changed the agreement, adding the sentence **"No Royalty is payable for Apps with a List Price of $0.00."**

Answer (score 9):

Apparently nobody. The developer gets $0. http://shiftyjelly.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/amazon-app-store-rotten-to-the-core/ via http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/j6neg/amazon_app_store_rotten_to_the_core/

Comment: If a developer gets $0, it means developer is paying...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Amazon who is paying for those apps. Amazon wants users to get used to using their store. The other answer provides better details.